Resizable Spacer in compose when keyboard is shown
In xml I could use something like that:
<Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

It will resize when keyboard is shown and "adjustResize" applied. Now in the same activity I'm trying to insert compose code that will have same behaviour, but so far no luck. I've tried
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(60.dp))

but it's completely ignoring keyboard event.
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.heightIn(4.dp, 60.dp))

but it's preferring minHeight for some reason so I can't even figure if it'll react on keyboard.
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.heightIn(4.dp, 60.dp).weight(1f))

but it's ignoring maxHeight though at least reacts on keyboard (still wrong result but something). Any ideas on how to get xml like behaviour?

I am not sure if I understood what exactly you want, but according to your XML sample, please try the weight Modifier:
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))


Yeah, I've tried it. Same as with heightIn(), its taking way to much space so buttons under going beyond screen until keyboard is shown. Maybe I should point some boundaries for parent Column? I suppose the problem is that I trying to use it inside parent ViewPager2. Because for now this behaviour is way different from xml one

@Kostya1375 Please edit your post and include all the necessary code showing how you embed the Composable in your ViewPager2. Then we can help you better.
